# Struts2 Access Static Method (GAE/J)

Tags: google-app-engine, struts2

I have set in struts.xml

```
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>
```

In my jsp, i tried to convert GAE key to string

```
<s:iterator var="itr" value="list" status="stat">
    <s:property value="@com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory@keyToString(key)"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Iterator and key works. But when trying to convert key to String, it doesn't display anything.
Do I have to import something in my jsp? Am I accessing the method correctly?

Comment: In the value of a property tag what does "key.class" produce? For sanity can you use this static method in your action to display something to console/logs?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new getKeyStr() in your bean:

```
public String getKeyStr() {
    return KeyFactory.keyToString(key);
}
```

And access to it in your jsp:

```
                <s:select key="userConfig.categories"
                            list="categories" 
                            listValue="getText(name)"
                            listKey="%{keyStr}" 
                            value="%{config.categories.{keyStr}}"
                            name="config.categories.key"
                            multiple="true"
                            size="%{categories.size()}"
                            required="true"
                            />
```